# How to get Location in onMapLongClick and send to another Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm using Google Maps API v2 in my project, and I want to get the location that the user long clicks on.

When the user does a long click on the map, I want to get the location and pass it to another Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very simple to set a long click listener on a GoogleMap reference, which gives you a LatLng reference with the exact coordinates that the user clicked.

You can then pass it as a Parcelable extra to the other Activity:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Intent ii = new Intent(MapActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        ii.putExtra("clicked_location", latLng);
        startActivity(ii);
    }
});
```

Then you can retrieve it in the other Activity using `getParcelableExtra()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

    Intent ii = getIntent();
    LatLng clickedLatLng = ii.getParcelableExtra("clicked_location");
    if (clickedLatLng != null) {
        //do something
    }
}
```